# Transferring Data in View Controllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, viewcontroller, data-transfer

I would like to transfer some data, for example an integer, from ViewController1 to ViewController2. How would I do that? In other words, how would I be able to access the information from ViewController1 in ViewController2? Please specify all the required code. Thanks!!

Comment: Can you tell us [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: "Please specify all the required code" ??? I learnt it myself, from  book, go read a book about iPhone development and it will explain all about this sort of stuff,

Answer (score 0):

When you push to the second view controller you will use some code like this...

```
MyViewController *vc2 = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2];
```

in order to pass information to it you need to set up a property in MyViewController.h file like this...

```
@property NSString *someNameProperty;
```

Then when you push do this...

```
MyViewController *vc2 = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];

vc2.someNameProperty = @"This is being passed to view controller 2";

[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2];
```

Then in vc2 you can access the same property `self.someNameProperty` and it will contain the value you passed in from vc1.

Hope this helps.